# Mostrar en orden los arrays y sus hijos

Tags: php, laravel

tengo un problema, quisiera hacer una aplicación para mostrar tareas y sus presupuestos correspondientes. Cada tarea puede tener subtareas y esas subtareas pueden tener sus propias subtareas, así infinitamente.

Para eso en la base de datos tengo tres campos: Id, Id_padre y presupuesto

Quiero que el orden de las tareas sea el siguiente. Donde se comprobaran todos los hijos de una tarea, antes de pasar a la siguiente. Algo así seria el orden.

Tarea 1
Tarea 1.1
Tarea 1.2
Tarea 1.2.1
Tarea 1.3
Tarea 2

Estoy usando Laravel, ya he podido crear un array donde contiene los padres y sus hijos con el siguiente codigo.

Modelo

```
public function parent()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'procedencia');
   }

   public function children()
   {
      return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'procedencia')->with('children');
   }
```

Controlador

```
$presupuesto_id = Presupuesto::whereNull('procedencia')->with('children')->get();

    $bandera = 0;
    $hijos = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($presupuesto_id); $i++){
        $hijos[$i][$bandera] = $presupuesto_id[$i];
        $hijos[$i][$bandera + 1] = $presupuesto_id[$i]->children;
    }

    return response()->json([$hijos]);
```

Ahi los tengo almacenado el padre, con un objeto donde contiene todos sus hijos. El problema es que no se como colocarlo en la pantalla en el orden que quiero. Si alguien pudiera ayudarme lo agradeceria

Comment: ¿Los datos están en una base de datos? Si es así, considera traerlos ya ordenados desde allí.

Comment: Si, están en la base de datos. Pero, no ordenados, como se haría esa consulta para traerlos ordenados?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes llamar al metodo `->children()` en lugar de la propiedad `->children`.

Una vez llames al metodo `->children()` obtienes el `queryBuilder` y tienes acceso a todos sus metodos, entre ellos `orderBy`.

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#orderby

En este ejemplo ordenas los hijos del presupuesto por el campo 'name'.

$hijos[$i][$bandera + 1] = $presupuesto_id[$i]->children()->orderBy('name')->get();